# render multiple components with enzyme shallow

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Is it possible to render more tan one component using enzyme's shallow?

I have the following  failing test:

```
  it('should have different ids for different checkboxes', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<div><Checkbox {...props} /><Checkbox {...props} /></div>)

    const inputs = wrapper.find('input')
    expect(inputs.length).toBe(1)
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to use enzyme's `mount` instead of `shallow`.  This is assuming your `Checkbox` component is what will give you the `input` that your test is looking for.  `shallow` doesn't render nested components.  As its name suggests, it does a shallow render of what you pass to it.  `mount`, on the other hand, will render nested components.

For more details on `mount` and `shallow`, check out their documentation:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md

All that being said, if this is a unit test then it shouldn't care about the output of `Checkbox`.  There would be unit tests for `Checkbox` to check its output.